# Copy range to clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy a range (specified in the VBA code: A1:I1) into the clipboard, so that the user can paste it whereever he like. How could I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Range has a Copy method on it, so to copy a range you can just do:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("A1:I1").Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh, nice! That was pretty easy.